# How do I access data from one buttonclick_event in the second buttonclick_event

Tags: c#, state, eventhandler

Will I just have to store the data somewhere or can the second buttonclick take advantage of the current state of the program that the first buttonclick has generated? The first buttonclick has generated local variables that the second buttonclick needs to access.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

namespace AnimalGame
{
    public partial class Game : Form
    {
        List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();

        public Game()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SpawnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cricketQuantity = Int32.Parse(CricketQuantityInput.Text);
            int frogQuantity = Int32.Parse(FrogQuantityInput.Text);
            int birdQuantity = Int32.Parse(BirdQuantityInput.Text);
            int mouseQuantity = Int32.Parse(MouseQuantityInput.Text);
            int snakeQuantity = Int32.Parse(SnakeQuantityInput.Text);
            int hunterQuantity = Int32.Parse(HunterQuantityInput.Text);

            for (var i = 0; i < cricketQuantity; i++)
            {
                animalList.Add(new Cricket());
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < frogQuantity; i++)
            {
                animalList.Add(new Frog());
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < birdQuantity; i++)
            {
                animalList.Add(new Bird());
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < mouseQuantity; i++)
            {
                animalList.Add(new Mouse());
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < snakeQuantity; i++)
            {
                animalList.Add(new Snake());
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < hunterQuantity; i++)
            {
                animalList.Add(new Hunter());
            }

            int totalAnimals = animalList.Count();
            TotalAnimalsTextBox.Text = Convert.ToString(totalAnimals);

            foreach (Animal a in animalList)
            {
                if (a is Cricket)
                {
                    Panel cricketPanel = new Panel();
                    cricketPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(9, 9);
                    cricketPanel.BackColor = Color.DarkGoldenrod;
                    a.Spawn();
                    GameGrid.Controls.Add(cricketPanel, a.XCoordinate, a.YCoordinate);
                }
                else if (a is Frog)
                {
                    Panel frogPanel = new Panel();
                    frogPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(9, 9);
                    frogPanel.BackColor = Color.Lime;
                    a.Spawn();
                    GameGrid.Controls.Add(frogPanel, a.XCoordinate, a.YCoordinate);
                }
                else if (a is Bird)
                {
                    Panel birdPanel = new Panel();
                    birdPanel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(9, 9);
                    birdPanel.BackColor = Color.SaddleBrown;
                    a.Spawn();
                    GameGrid.Controls.Add(birdPanel, a.XCoordinate, a.YCoordinate);
                }


            }
        }   

        private void NextMoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // this code needs to access the current object locations above and "move" them to another cell in
            // the grid
        }
    }

}

public abstract class Animal
{
    private int xCoordinate;
    private int yCoordinate;
    public abstract void Move();
    public void Spawn()
    {
        Random locationX = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        var spawnX = locationX.Next(0, 50);
        Random locationY = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        var spawnY = locationY.Next(0, 50);
        xCoordinate = spawnX;
        yCoordinate = spawnY;   
    }

    public int XCoordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return xCoordinate;
        }

        set
        {
            xCoordinate = value;
        }

    }
    public int YCoordinate
    {
        get
        {
            return yCoordinate;
        }

        set
        {
            if (yCoordinate > 50)
            {
                yCoordinate = 50;
            }

            else if ( yCoordinate < 0)
            {
                yCoordinate = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                yCoordinate = value;
            }
        }
    }
}

class Cricket : Animal
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Random direction = new Random();
        // the Cricket only moves one cell at a time.
        // 0 = Up
        // 1 = Right 
        // 2 = Down
        // 3 = Left
        var selectionDirection = direction.Next(0, 4);
        switch (selectionDirection)
        {
            case 0:
                YCoordinate -= 1;
                break;
            case 1:
                XCoordinate += 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                YCoordinate += 1;
                break;
            case 3:
                XCoordinate -= 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Frog : Animal
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Random direction = new Random();
        // the Frog moves 3 cells at a time.
        // 0 = Up
        // 1 = Right 
        // 2 = Down
        // 3 = Left
        var selectionDirection = direction.Next(0, 4);
        switch (selectionDirection)
        {
            case 0:
                YCoordinate -= 3;
                break;
            case 1:
                XCoordinate += 3;
                break;
            case 2:
                YCoordinate += 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                XCoordinate -= 3;
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Bird : Animal
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Random direction = new Random();
        // the Bird moves 5 cells at a time.
        // 0 = Up
        // 1 = Right 
        // 2 = Down
        // 3 = Left
        var selectionDirection = direction.Next(0, 4);
        switch (selectionDirection)
        {
            case 0:
                YCoordinate -= 4;
                break;
            case 1:
                XCoordinate += 4;
                break;
            case 2:
                YCoordinate += 4;
                break;
            case 3:
                XCoordinate -= 4;
                break;
        }
    }
}

class Mouse : Animal
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Random direction = new Random();
        // the Mouse moves 2 cells at a time.
        // 0 = Up
        // 1 = Right 
        // 2 = Down
        // 3 = Left
        var selectionDirection = direction.Next();
        switch (selectionDirection)
        {
            case 0:
                YCoordinate -= 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                XCoordinate += 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                YCoordinate += 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                XCoordinate -= 2;
                break;
        }

    }
}

class Snake : Animal
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Random direction = new Random();
        // the Mouse moves 4 cells at a time.
        // 0 = Up
        // 1 = Right 
        // 2 = Down
        // 3 = Left
        var selectionDirection = direction.Next();
        switch (selectionDirection)
        {
            case 0:
                YCoordinate -= 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                XCoordinate += 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                YCoordinate += 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                XCoordinate -= 2;
                break;
        }

    }
}

class Hunter : Animal
{
    public override void Move()
    {
        Random direction = new Random();
        // the Hunter moves 2 cells at a time.
        // 0 = Up
        // 1 = Right 
        // 2 = Down
        // 3 = Left
        var selectionDirection = direction.Next();
        switch (selectionDirection)
        {
            case 0:
                YCoordinate -= 2;
                break;
            case 1:
                XCoordinate += 2;
                break;
            case 2:
                YCoordinate += 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                XCoordinate -= 2;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: That depends on the code you're using. Maybe you can calculate from local variables whether the first button has been clicked or maybe you can't. Depends on how local is "local" and what is stored in these variables.

Comment: Or in other words: we'd have to see the code.

Comment: It's a multiple file project. Would you prefer I upload the entire project? I don't know that you will have enough context to understand what's going on in just this file.

Comment: Are those buttons appear on the same form?

Comment: I am adding these "characters" to a tablelayoutpanel grid I have constructed. The spawn function randomly assigns them to a grid in the 50x50 layout. The movebutton needs to update their location within certain parameters that have been designated in their classes.

Comment: yes Andrii, they are on the same form.

Comment: So what object you need to access from NextMoveButton_Click?

Comment: The panel objects that are created in the foreach loop.

Comment: And please post Animal class. The solution will depend on there is stores it's location or not.

Comment: Okay, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all `Panels` from `GameGrid.Controls` collection. You can iterate through those controls and do your logic.

If you need to know which `Animal` belongs you which `Panel` you can create a dictionary field and map each `Animal` to a `Panel`:

```
public partial class Game : Form
{
    List<Animal> animalList = new List<Animal>();
    Dictionary<Animal, Panel> animalPanels = new Dictionary<Animal, Panel>();

    ...

            // For each animal.
            a.Spawn();
            GameGrid.Controls.Add(birdPanel, a.XCoordinate, a.YCoordinate);
            animalPanels.Add(a, birdPanel);
    ...

    private void NextMoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Access GameGrid.Controls.

        // Or animalPanels.
    }
}
```

Comment: @EricBooker, did it help?